# Spring Executable jar error on Windows

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat7

I have created executable jar following [these instructions](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2012/11/standalone-web-application-with.html).

I am using STS programm on the MacOS. After creating jar file it works fine on MacOS but on Windows I get following error:

```
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.30
Apr 12, 2017 6:42:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig init
SEVERE: Exception fixing docBase for context []
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\John\.extract\webapps\ROOT.war (The system cannot find the file specified)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ExpandWar.expand(ExpandWar.java:113)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.fixDocBase(ContextConfig.java:720)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.init(ContextConfig.java:843)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:387)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:401)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Apr 12, 2017 6:42:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart
SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid or unreadable WAR file : C:\Users\John\.extract\webapps\ROOT.war
        at org.apache.naming.resources.WARDirContext.setDocBase(WARDirContext.java:136)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4906)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5086)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Apr 12, 2017 6:42:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error in resourceStart()
Apr 12, 2017 6:42:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
Apr 12, 2017 6:42:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
Apr 12, 2017 6:42:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
```

My pom.xml contains following part for creating jar:

```
 <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>tomcat-run</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exec-war-only</goal>
                </goals>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <server>192.168.1.85</server>
                    <path>/</path>
                    <enableNaming>false</enableNaming>
                    <finalName>guard_server.jar</finalName>
                    <charset>utf-8</charset>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Is there any solution?

UPD: After compiling the project on Windows the problem remains so it is not platform problem.